# How to include FFI in OS X?

Tags: c, include, closures

I'm having trouble building [this project](https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c) with the FFI extension enabled. To isolate the problem, I'm trying to compile [this example](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/libffi-dev/html/Closure-Example.html) (included in full below).

I'm using OS X 10.13.2, Xcode 9.2 with Command Line Tools installed (confirmed that **/usr/include/ffi/ffi.h** exists). I modified the example so the include line reads `include <ffi/ffi.h>`.

Invoking the compiler with no options, I get the following:

```
$ gcc closure.test.c
closure.test.c:23:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ffi_closure_alloc' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  closure = ffi_closure_alloc(sizeof(ffi_closure), &bound_puts);
            ^
closure.test.c:23:11: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'ffi_closure *' (aka 'struct ffi_closure *') from
      'int' [-Wint-conversion]
  closure = ffi_closure_alloc(sizeof(ffi_closure), &bound_puts);
          ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
closure.test.c:35:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ffi_prep_closure_loc' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
          if (ffi_prep_closure_loc(closure, &cif, puts_binding,
              ^
closure.test.c:45:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ffi_closure_free' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  ffi_closure_free(closure);
  ^
4 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ffi_closure_alloc", referenced from:
      _main in closure-7b0e9b.o
  "_ffi_closure_free", referenced from:
      _main in closure-7b0e9b.o
  "_ffi_prep_cif", referenced from:
      _main in closure-7b0e9b.o
  "_ffi_prep_closure_loc", referenced from:
      _main in closure-7b0e9b.o
  "_ffi_type_pointer", referenced from:
      _main in closure-7b0e9b.o
  "_ffi_type_sint32", referenced from:
      _main in closure-7b0e9b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What options/modifications do I need to correct this?

### Source of `closure.test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ffi.h>

/* Acts like puts with the file given at time of enclosure. */
void puts_binding(ffi_cif *cif, void *ret, void* args[],
                  void *stream)
{
  *(ffi_arg *)ret = fputs(*(char **)args[0], (FILE *)stream);
}

typedef int (*puts_t)(char *);

int main()
{
  ffi_cif cif;
  ffi_type *args[1];
  ffi_closure *closure;

  void *bound_puts;
  int rc;

  /* Allocate closure and bound_puts */
  closure = ffi_closure_alloc(sizeof(ffi_closure), &bound_puts);

  if (closure)
    {
      /* Initialize the argument info vectors */
      args[0] = &ffi_type_pointer;

      /* Initialize the cif */
      if (ffi_prep_cif(&cif, FFI_DEFAULT_ABI, 1,
                       &ffi_type_sint, args) == FFI_OK)
        {
          /* Initialize the closure, setting stream to stdout */
          if (ffi_prep_closure_loc(closure, &cif, puts_binding,
                                   stdout, bound_puts) == FFI_OK)
            {
              rc = ((puts_t)bound_puts)("Hello World!");
              /* rc now holds the result of the call to fputs */
            }
        }
    }

  /* Deallocate both closure, and bound_puts */
  ffi_closure_free(closure);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bad news: Mac OS indeed does not have the functions you are missing. Check out [this](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-05-06-a-tour-of-mablockclosure.html), particularly __Closure Allocation__ section.

Comment: @user58697 Strange, really?  I see some corroboration of missing `ffi_prep_cif_var` on MacOS.  But closures seem to be there...there are discussions of current bugs in closures on MacOS...such as [this one](https://github.com/libffi/libffi/issues/355) mentioning it recently, and `ffi_closure_alloc` is referred to [here in 2009](https://sourceware.org/ml/libffi-discuss/2009/msg00236.html).  Are they talking about something different?

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/msg115649 is more evidence.

Answer (score 8):

Well, seems like you can fix it doing this:

```
$ cd
$ git clone https://github.com/libffi/libffi
$ cd libffi/
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

This will build `libffi` from source and it will work even if you have `libffi` installed from `brew`, because this new version will be installed under `/usr/local` and not in `Cellar`.

Then you don't need to change the `#include`, keep it like `#include <ffi.h>`, open a terminal to the folder your isolated c source is and issue `gcc -o ffi -lffi ffi.c` (assuming it's the source file you have).

```
teixeira: ~/etudes_c $ ./ffi
Hello World!
```

Comment: I get the following error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ffi_closure_alloc", referenced from:
      _main in closure-77e81a.o
  "_ffi_closure_free", referenced from:
      _main in closure-77e81a.o
  "_ffi_prep_closure_loc", referenced from:
      _main in closure-77e81a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: In what step of the procedure I told you does this error occur ?

Comment: At the build point: `gcc -o ffi -lffi ffi.c` —double-checked, ran all the steps beforehand.

Comment: Have you changed the `#include` to `#include <ffi.h>` ?

Answer (score 7):

`brew install libffi` worked for me with one additional step. When you run `brew info libffi` you'll see the following:

```sh
# For compilers to find libffi you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include"

# For pkg-config to find libffi you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Exporting these env vars allowed rvm to work correctly.

Comment: This worked, but I did not need to export the environment variables.

Comment: This worked for me

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"`

`gem install ffi`

Answer (score 1):

`brew install libffi` is the quick solution to help me solve the ld issue.

Comment: This worked. I did not need to export env variables as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65751929/35690).